# nodejs modify data during piping from source to destination

Tags: node.js

I have a simple http server that will pipe all data from the req object(source) to res(destination) object. but how can I change output data from source, before writing it to the destionation?
by changing data I mean sth simple like calling `toUpperCase()` on data.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.method.toLowerCase() != 'post')
        res.end() ;
    req.pipe(res) ;
}).listen(9090) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own [Transform stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) like this that sits in between the two streams:

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var TransformStream = require('stream').Transform;

function UpperStream() {
  TransformStream.call(this);
}
inherits(UpperStream, TransformStream);
UpperStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; ++i) {
    var ch = chunk[i];
    // Check for lowercase character
    if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) {
      // Make it uppercase
      chunk[i] &= ~32;
    }
  }
  cb(null, chunk);
};
```

Then you could just do something like:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.method.toLowerCase() != 'post')
        return res.end() ;
    req.pipe(new UpperStream()).pipe(res) ;
}).listen(9090) ;
```

Comment: why sending 'null' to the callback at 'cb(null , chunk)'?

Comment: That signals that there was no error processing the chunk.

Comment: thanks for your good answer, can you name some popular packages for this purpose(if there is any) at the end of your answer? I want to keep your answer as a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, but you can search for modules on [npmjs.org](http://npmjs.org) and other npm repository indexing sites like [node-modules.com](http://node-modules.com).